# Drupal 8 restresource: No route found

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to create a rest endpoint. The way i do it is i first create a module with `drupal generate:module` then add the rest dependency and then create a restresource with `drupal generate:plugin:rest:resource`. This all works fine, the endpoint i created even shows up in the module restui with the following path: `/api/v1/articles`.
The problem is when i go to the endpoint i created i get the following error:

```
{ 
  "message": "No route found for \"GET /api/v1/articles\""
}
```

Cache rebuilding doesn't fix the problem for me and when i look in the routing table there is indeed no routing added for `/api/v1/articles`.
Is there something i am forgetting to do?

This is the generated rest resource:

```
namespace Drupal\api_articles\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a resource to get view modes by entity and bundle.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "article_rest_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Article rest resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/v1/articles",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/api/v1/articles"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ArticleRestResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * A current user instance.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * Constructs a Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param array $serializer_formats
   *   The available serialization formats.
   * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   *   A logger instance.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $current_user
   *   A current user instance.
   */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    array $serializer_formats,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    AccountProxyInterface $current_user) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $serializer_formats, $logger);

    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('api_articles'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Responds to GET requests.
   *
   * Returns a list of bundles for specified entity.
   *
   * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
   *   Throws exception expected.
   */
  public function get() {

    // You must to implement the logic of your REST Resource here.
    // Use current user after pass authentication to validate access.
    if (!$this->currentUser->hasPermission('access content')) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }

    return new ResourceResponse("Implement REST State GET!");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [REST and Application Integration](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/third_party/8.2.x):

> The content type for the data you send, or the accept type for the
> data you are receiving, must be set to 'application/hal+json'.

So the following steps are required:

1. Enable the HAL module.
2. In the resource configuration, under *Accepted request formats* enable *hal_json*.
3. [[I]nform Drupal about the serialization format you are using](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview).  So either send the Content-Type header with hal+json (e.g. POST), or add `?_format=hal+json` to the URL (e.g. GET).

This can also be caused by missing this line in `@RestResource` annotation, but you already have it:

```
"create" = "/api/v1/articles"
```

Comment: It's not `https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create` anymore. It's just `create`. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2802677

Answer (score 0):

So the problems was with upgrading from 8.1.9 to 8.2.0. This broke the RestUI module which i used to assign the endpoints.

Comment: so how did you fix this? downgrade?

Comment: No restui has a patch which fixes the problem for now. Soon they will  release it i guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that restui doesn't create a config file for your resource, you can create it yourself if you want to work with stable versions (8.x-1.12) only. The dev version of restui already fixes this.

Link: https://www.drupal.org/node/2816433